# chef-server SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: chef-infra

I keep getting error after running

```
➜  chef knife ssh 'name:beautifulprayer' -x ubuntu

WARNING: Failed to connect to beautifulprayer -- SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Not sure why. Here is info about the node:

```
➜  chef knife node show beautifulprayer
Node Name:   beautifulprayer
Environment: _default
FQDN:        beautifulprayer
IP:          104.131.0.191
Run List:    recipe[sudo]
Roles:
Recipes:
Platform:    ubuntu 14.04
Tags:
```

Comment: Does a  `ping beautifulprayer` works ? I'm pretty sure not as there's no domain to ask for this host IP and that's the error message you get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 beautifulprayer
```

is probably not a FQDN and not resolvable. While you want to fix this you can try:

```
knife ssh 'name:beautifulprayer' -a ipaddress -x ubuntu
```

In this case, knife will use the ipaddress attribute instead of the (broken) FQDN.

Comment: I initially did `knife bookstrap IPADDRESS` which then chef named the IPADDRESS server as the name of the server (from DigitalOcean)

Comment: When I bootstrap a node which does not yet have a DNS record, I can use `knife bootstrap <IP> -N the.future.fqdn.of.this.server.com`.  You may want to check my knife plugin for DigitalOcean which does this by default: https://github.com/rmoriz/knife-digital_ocean#create-a-droplet

Comment: I get this error now :( `FATAL: 1 node found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the connection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribute.`

Comment: You're a boss @Roland